# Why do the circles not disappear after being drawn?

Tags: python, pygame

When I run this code it just make a trail of circles instead of one circle moving. The code is as follows:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

circX = 250 
circY= 250
diffX= 0
diffY=0

while True:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == QUIT:
   pygame.quit()
   sys.exit()
 diffX += random.randint(-1,1)
 diffY += random.randint(-1,1)
 circX += diffX
 circY += diffY
 circLocate = (circX,circY)
 pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, WHITE, circLocate, 10, 0)
 pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Pygame is like a canvas, its not the same object everytime. Each time you draw you create a new circle. You would need to remove the circle you previously drew to make the circle "move"

Comment: @microsby0 Other way 'round... You get the _same_ canvas every time so need to erase your previous drawing.

Comment: It was poor phrasing, I meant "Pygame is like a canvas, the circle is not the same object everytime". Thanks for catching that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This addition should clear your screen each time you want the circle to move

```
while True:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == QUIT:
   pygame.quit()
   sys.exit()
 windowSurface.fill(WHITE) //add this line to clear the screen
 diffX += random.randint(-1,1)
 diffY += random.randint(-1,1)
 circX += diffX
 circY += diffY
 circLocate = (circX,circY)
 pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, WHITE, circLocate, 10, 0)
 pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the screen so it appears like the object is moving.

```
windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
```

As such:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

circX = 250 
circY= 250
diffX= 0
diffY=0

while True:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == QUIT:
   pygame.quit()
   sys.exit()
 diffX += random.randint(-1,1)
 diffY += random.randint(-1,1)
 circX += diffX
 circY += diffY
 circLocate = (circX,circY)
 windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
 pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, WHITE, circLocate, 10, 0)
 pygame.display.flip()
```

However, make sure that the `windowSurface.fill()` is **before** the `pygame.draw.circle()`, else, it will only show a white screen.